# Flutter error when converting a list to a json object removing some keys

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an error when trying to convert a list of my object to json

My error:

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'RxList<ItemStockEntryModel>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'
```

My model code:

```
class StockEntryModel {
  final int? id;
  final double costFreight;
  final List<ItemStockEntryModel> items;

  StockEntryModel({
    this.id,
    required this.costFreight,
    required this.items,
  });

  factory StockEntryModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      StockEntryModel(
        id: json['id'],
        costFreight: json['costFreight'],
        items: json['itemStockEntries'],
      );
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'id': id,
        'costFreight': costFreight,
        'itemStockEntries': items,
      };
  Map<String, dynamic> itemsToMap() => {
        'data': items,
      };
  String itemsToJson() {
    var data = {};
    final test = itemsToMap()['data'];
    final mappedItems = Map<String, dynamic>.from(test) // the error occurs here on test variable
      ..removeWhere((key, value) => value == null || key == 'product');
    print(json.encode(mappedItems));
    data['itemStockEntries'] = mappedItems;

    return json.encode(data);
  }
}
```

*my goal is to return a json object like this*

```
// is not complete, only example...
{
    "itemStockEntries": {
        "data": [{
            "id": 2
        }, {
            "id": 3
        }]
    }
}
```

*but i need remove keys if this value is null and my key product..*

I saw some similar errors, but I couldn't find the one that actually causes it
sorry for my bad english =(

My solution based on Loren codes. I expect to help someone also

```
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'id': id,
        'costFreight': costFreight,
        'itemStockEntries': items.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList(),
      };
  Map<String, dynamic> itemsToMap() => {
        'data': items
            .map(
              (e) => e.toJson()
                ..removeWhere(
                    (key, value) => key == 'product' || value == null),
            )
            .toList(),
      };

  Map<String, dynamic> modelToJson() {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = {};
    data['itemStockEntries'] = itemsToMap();
    data['costFreight'] = costFreight;
    print(json.encode(data));
    return data;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.from` method on a map needs a map to be passed into it, and you're passing in a list. So `removeWhere` is looking for keys and values which don't exist the way you're doing it.

So you could clear that first error getting rid of the `itemsToMap` function and changing the first 2 lines of your `itemsToJson` function to this.

```
var data = {'data': items}; // an actual map that you can pass in
final mappedItems = Map<String, dynamic>.from(data) // no more error here
```

But that's still a map with just a single key with a value of a list. So the `removeWhere` is not going to do anything of value here.

The `List<ItemStockEntryModel>` is what you need to be iterating through.

Assuming you have json serialization setup in your `ItemStockEntryModel`, this is closer to what you need to do. Not a complete example because I don't know what that model looks like, but it should give you the idea.

```
 String itemsToJson() {
    Map data = {};
    List<String> jsonList = []; // new list of json strings to pass into data map

    for (final item in items) {
      if (// item meets whatever conditions you need) {
        final jsonItem = json.encode(item);
        jsonList.add(jsonItem);
      }
    }
    data['itemStockEntries'] = {'data': jsonList};


    return json.encode(data);
  }
```

Comment: Loren, thanks a lot. Now i understand what is necessary to reach my objective. Based on your answer i arrived in coding below (is in the question)